# Multiple git account doesn't work with Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, macos, ssh, terminal

Due to my customer's privacy requirement, I've got create multiple account to access different git. With some helps, I've created the file `config` and multiple ssh keys in dir `~/.ssh`. **Using terminal, I've been able to perform all kind of action to the git**. However, if I use XCode to perform those action, it stated that `failed to authenticate`.

[image: xcode failed]

This is the content of `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host bitbucket-myAccount2
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/acc2ssh
```

Inside `~/.ssh/`, I've already had `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`, `acc2ssh`, `acc2ssh.pub`. `id_rsa` is my usual git account, and `acc2ssh` is the other private account.

If I use terminal, it's alright, but it ask for passphrase everytime.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket-myAccount2:privateTeam/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket-myAccount2:privateTeam/project.git (push)

$ git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/$myUser/.ssh/acc2ssh': 
Already up-to-date.
```

How do I config this to work in both xcode and terminal?

Additional question: How do I make the terminal to remember my passphrase?

**UPDATE**

Due to the confusion, I'll add more details about the git remote:

I'm checkout out the git via:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket-myAccount2:privateTeam/project.git
```

Because if I use the ssh provided from bitbucket, it won't work (access denied):

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:privateTeam/project.git
repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But Xcode seems to doesn't recognize the host `bitbucket-myAccount2` as @Jakuje pointed out. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: For the additional question: use `ssh-agent`

Comment: @1615903 wow, thanks! I've got that to work via https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Answer (score 0):

XCode (most probably) does not read your `~/.ssh/config` because it is not based on OpenSSH. You should use just the hostname as it is and provide the correct private key.

If the other one (in default location) is still picked up, move it away/rename from default location (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) and update the `~/.ssh/config` to reflect this change. For example:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

Comment: okay, so using the base host name works for xcode, but can't via terminal now, due to `access denied`. How should I config `~/.ssh/config` to work with terminal?

Comment: *"move it away from default location and update the ~/.ssh/config to reflect this change."*

Comment: I'm sorry but move `what` from `default location`? what's the `default location` you're referring to?

Comment: Default location is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: I don't get it... I have 2 ssh-keys in `~/.ssh/`, using both of them to pull from git. Please be more specific. I'm a noob at this, sorry.

Comment: See the edit. Just rename `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to  `~/.ssh/id_rsa2` for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143772/discussion-between-eddie-and-jakuje).